# taking text/integers from a text file and inserting the data into a 2D array in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array

I've been reading around the forums and have struggled to find any posts that really help me get to the bottom of my issue, so I'm writing as a last resort

I have a text file which contains this data:

Jones 14

Abrams 15

Smith 19

Jones 9

Alexander 22

Smith 20

Smith 17

Taylor 42

Jones 2

Hooper 12

Jones 11

I need to order the names alphabetically and then with duplicate names, order them in ascending order by number (aka age)

I first began by attempting to do the readalllines function, and then put these lines into an array, the code is as follows:

```
Dim orfi As String = "P:\names_ages.txt"
arrline() = File.ReadAllLines(orfi)
```

then i attempted to split the lines via the split function where the space is the delimiter:

```
Split(arrline(), " ")
```

Upon trying this, i kept getting an error telling me i couldn't split the string in the array, which confused me, and now I don't know how to get this data into a 2D array, based on name and age.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be v grateful

Full code:

```
Imports System.IO
```

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    Dim info(name, age) As Integer
    Dim orfi As String = "P:\names_ages.txt"
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim loopswap As Boolean
    Dim temp As Integer
    Dim maxIndex As Integer
    Dim arrline() As String
    maxIndex = arrline.Length - 1

    'attempting to put lines into an array 
    Sub Main()
    Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("P:\names_ages.txt")
    Dim values(lines.Length - 1, 1) As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        Dim parts() As String = lines(i).Split(" ")
          values(i, 0) = parts(0)
          values(i, 1) = parts(1)
    Next

    'parsing file lines into an array and then further parsing them? 
    arrline() = File.ReadAllLines(orfi)
    Split(arrline(), " ")

    'bubble that sorts each line alphabetically
    Do
        loopswap = False
        For c = 0 To maxIndex - 1 
            If arrline(c) > arrline(c + 1) Then
                temp = arrline(c)
                arrline(c) = arrline(c + 1)
                arrline(c + 1) = temp

                loopswap = True
            End If
        Next
    Loop While loopswap
    'bubble that sorts each line depending on age in ascending order 
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: This sounds like a college project of some sort... Perhaps provide the full routine rather than single lines.

Comment: I should note that `ReadAllLines()` returns an array of strings and you are attempting to split the array. I think you are better performing a while loop and use `ReadLine()`.

Comment: question now contains full (poorly written) code. I'm really quite new to this, so I'm sorry if this is really quite awful to read haha

Answer (score 0):

This is broadly what you want, it isn't perfect but it will give you a better understanding of what is required. I've added a structure to keep things organised.

If you're curious about `sr.peek()`, see: [StreamReader.Peek()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hope this helps.

```
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        dim fileContents as  List(Of CustomerInfo) = ReadFile("c:\names_ages.txt")
        for each customer As CustomerInfo In fileContents
            console.WriteLine("Name: " + customer.Surname & ", Age: " & customer.age.ToString())
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
    Structure CustomerInfo
        Dim Surname As String
        Dim Age As Integer
    End Structure
    Private Function ReadFile(path As String) As List(Of CustomerInfo)
        Dim custInfo As New List(Of CustomerInfo)
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path)
        Do While sr.Peek() >= 0 'Check that the new line contains a character
            Dim ci As New CustomerInfo
            Dim customer As New List(Of String) 'Declare a new list
            customer = sr.ReadLine().Split(" ").ToList() 'Split string and call ToList()
            ci.Surname = customer(0).Trim() 'Select First element in list
            ci.Age = customer(1).ToString().Trim() 'Select second element in list
            'This is not a robust way to do things... It relies on data fitting a very specific format.
            custInfo.Add(ci) 'Add structure to the list of customerInfo
        Loop
        Return custInfo
    End Function
End Module
```

As for sorting... I'm not sure if you're allowed to use `Linq` but here is a sort (not a bubble sort, granted...)

```
Dim sortedList = From f In fileContents Order By f.Surname
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this Daniel, this is really awesome and incredibly helpful for some future coding. The only issue is that my prof wants me to used either bubble or insertion sort to order the names and ages, and thus I presumed I needed a 2D array?

Comment: Unless a 2D array was specifically asked for, a list of structure will suffice, it may even get you marks. When loop over your list, you can do list.surname and list.age rather than accessing the position in array. It's more readable and provides a succinct structure. N.B. This list is akin to a 2D array.

Comment: We used vis studio 2010 at college, and it seems to not be picking up the stream command?? Thanks for clarifying the list tidbit!!

Comment: You need to import System.IO

Comment: @yttamyttam I've updated the answer with code that can be compiled. Copy/paste into a new visual studio console app project and run :)

Comment: @yttamyttam If this helps, please mark question as answered